# Armbian binary compatibility with Raspbian

Tags: cross-compilation, software-compilation

I was wondering if one can compile binaries on Armbian to be used on Raspbian (without using cross-compilation tools)? Is there binary compatibility? Do I need to link libraries statically (would that even work?)?

My idea was to get a Armbian machine with 2 GB (not the Raspberry, thus) and use this as a simple strategy to compile stuff that needs more than 1GB to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, **Yes**, they will work. Both repositories use the same *upstream* code to build their packages.

That is, `armhf` binaries from armbian will run on an `armhf` raspbian.

Your problem won't binary compatibility but dependency compatibility. Using a statically linked executable will resolve the dependency compatibility at the expense of binary size.

---

Debian packages are compiled against dependencies as they exist in the repository. That is, if you're application needs `glibc`, debian will use the `glibc` dependency **from that release**.

Imagine this scenario, two packages

**Raspbian**: `MyApplication-1.0~raspbian` built against `glibc-X.Y~raspbian`

**Armbian**:  `MyApplication-1.0~armbian` built against `glibc-A.B~armbian`

If there are differences between the two versions of `glibc`, then if you install `MyApplication-1.0~armbian.deb` on a raspbian system, you will likely have an error when starting the application or a bug of some sort that may crop up.

If the dependencies are equivalent or compatible, then the package will work as intended.

You can, if you like, choose to install all the `armbian` dependencies for a given package by simply adding the armbian repos to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, however this will potential conflict with `raspbian` versions of the same packages, causing a broken system

There are a few further complications, for example there are build dependencies `build-dep` which are seperate from package runtime dependencies

---

The proper way to do this is to port the package by rebuilding the `armbian` package *from source* against the `raspbian` dependencies. This is not guaranteed to succeed (sometimes things are actually incompatible), but when done correctly is very reliable.

This is basically what is used to create `backport` repositories in desktop ubuntu/debian

Explaining how to build debian packages from scratch is outside the scope of this question, but I would point you to [my answer on `ubuntu.se`](https://askubuntu.com/a/482387/5042) for an introduction to what it takes.

Building packages can be done on a desktop pc with the proper cross-compile or on Raspberry with native compiler.

Comment: My apologies, I had interpreted the question as being about repo packages. I will leave the answer up since it may still be useful, In any case cross-compilation is very simple but confusing and I would recommend you learn how to use it.

Comment: My first attempt was doing cross-compilation but run into problems. I will do a separate question on this